# Find the source code for computing size of a docker image

Tags: docker, go, docker-ce

I have heard the number is not equal to all sizes of layers adding together inside an image. And it is also not the size of disk space it occupies.

Now I want to check the logic by source code (in this repo: https://github.com/docker/docker-ce), because seeing is believing! But after navigating the code for a lot of time, I found that I was not able to find the real imag-size-computing code.

So which function/file is the docker used to perform the size logic?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Before digging too deep, you may find it useful to understand how Linux implements the overlay filesystem. I include a bit on this the first exercise of my [intro presentation's build section](https://sudo-bmitch.github.io/presentations/docker-intro/presentation.html#building). The [demo notes](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/presentations/blob/docker-intro/docker-intro/demo.md) include each of the commands I'm running and it gives you an idea of how layers are merged, and what happens when you add/modify/delete from a layer.

---

This is implementation dependent, based on your host OS and the graph driver being used. I'm taking the example of a Linux OS and Overlay2 since that's the most common use case.

It starts by looking at the image [layer storage size](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/8a582e89b407639018e067123eb17f61dbfd10ee/components/engine/daemon/images/image_unix.go#L20):

```
// GetContainerLayerSize returns the real size & virtual size of the container.
func (i *ImageService) GetContainerLayerSize(containerID string) (int64, int64) {
    var (
        sizeRw, sizeRootfs int64
        err                error
    )

    // Safe to index by runtime.GOOS as Unix hosts don't support multiple
    // container operating systems.
    rwlayer, err := i.layerStores[runtime.GOOS].GetRWLayer(containerID)
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("Failed to compute size of container rootfs %v: %v", containerID, err)
        return sizeRw, sizeRootfs
    }
    defer i.layerStores[runtime.GOOS].ReleaseRWLayer(rwlayer)

    sizeRw, err = rwlayer.Size()
    if err != nil {
        logrus.Errorf("Driver %s couldn't return diff size of container %s: %s",
            i.layerStores[runtime.GOOS].DriverName(), containerID, err)
        // FIXME: GetSize should return an error. Not changing it now in case
        // there is a side-effect.
        sizeRw = -1
    }

    if parent := rwlayer.Parent(); parent != nil {
        sizeRootfs, err = parent.Size()
        if err != nil {
            sizeRootfs = -1
        } else if sizeRw != -1 {
            sizeRootfs += sizeRw
        }
    }
    return sizeRw, sizeRootfs
}
```

In there is a call to `layerStores` which itself is [a mapping to layer.Store](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/f6756a1630dc152c87c5a7cd59e68739d10a8901/components/engine/daemon/images/service.go#L38):

```
// ImageServiceConfig is the configuration used to create a new ImageService
type ImageServiceConfig struct {
    ContainerStore            containerStore
    DistributionMetadataStore metadata.Store
    EventsService             *daemonevents.Events
    ImageStore                image.Store
    LayerStores               map[string]layer.Store
    MaxConcurrentDownloads    int
    MaxConcurrentUploads      int
    MaxDownloadAttempts       int
    ReferenceStore            dockerreference.Store
    RegistryService           registry.Service
    TrustKey                  libtrust.PrivateKey
}
```

Digging into the `layer.Store` implementation for `GetRWLayer`, there is the [following definition](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/layer/layer_store.go#L577):

```
func (ls *layerStore) GetRWLayer(id string) (RWLayer, error) {
    ls.locker.Lock(id)
    defer ls.locker.Unlock(id)

    ls.mountL.Lock()
    mount := ls.mounts[id]
    ls.mountL.Unlock()
    if mount == nil {
        return nil, ErrMountDoesNotExist
    }

    return mount.getReference(), nil
}
```

Following that to find the `Size` implementation for the mount reference, there is [this function](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/layer/mounted_layer.go#L50) that gets into the specific graph driver:

```
func (ml *mountedLayer) Size() (int64, error) {
    return ml.layerStore.driver.DiffSize(ml.mountID, ml.cacheParent())
}
```

Looking at the overlay2 graph driver to find the [DiffSize function](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/8a582e89b407639018e067123eb17f61dbfd10ee/components/engine/daemon/graphdriver/overlay2/overlay.go#L730):

```
func (d *Driver) DiffSize(id, parent string) (size int64, err error) {
    if useNaiveDiff(d.home) || !d.isParent(id, parent) {
        return d.naiveDiff.DiffSize(id, parent)
    }
    return directory.Size(context.TODO(), d.getDiffPath(id))
}
```

That is calling `naiveDiff` which [implements Size in the graphDriver package](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/8a582e89b407639018e067123eb17f61dbfd10ee/components/engine/daemon/graphdriver/fsdiff.go#L160):

```
func (gdw *NaiveDiffDriver) DiffSize(id, parent string) (size int64, err error) {
    driver := gdw.ProtoDriver

    changes, err := gdw.Changes(id, parent)
    if err != nil {
        return
    }

    layerFs, err := driver.Get(id, "")
    if err != nil {
        return
    }
    defer driver.Put(id)

    return archive.ChangesSize(layerFs.Path(), changes), nil
}
```

Following `archive.ChangeSize` we can see this [implementation](https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/master/components/engine/pkg/archive/changes.go#L367):

```
// ChangesSize calculates the size in bytes of the provided changes, based on newDir.
func ChangesSize(newDir string, changes []Change) int64 {
    var (
        size int64
        sf   = make(map[uint64]struct{})
    )
    for _, change := range changes {
        if change.Kind == ChangeModify || change.Kind == ChangeAdd {
            file := filepath.Join(newDir, change.Path)
            fileInfo, err := os.Lstat(file)
            if err != nil {
                logrus.Errorf("Can not stat %q: %s", file, err)
                continue
            }

            if fileInfo != nil && !fileInfo.IsDir() {
                if hasHardlinks(fileInfo) {
                    inode := getIno(fileInfo)
                    if _, ok := sf[inode]; !ok {
                        size += fileInfo.Size()
                        sf[inode] = struct{}{}
                    }
                } else {
                    size += fileInfo.Size()
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return size
}
```

At which point we are using `os.Lstat` to return a struct that includes `Size` on each entry that is an add or modify to each directory. Note that this is one of several possible paths the code takes, but I believe it's one of the more common ones for this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can get size in

```
$ docker image ls
REPOSITORY  TAG                 IMAGE ID            CREATED             SIZE
nginx       1.12-alpine         24ed1c575f81        2 years ago        15.5MB
```

this function code is here
https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/5a0987be93654b685927c2e5c2d18ac01022d20c/components/cli/cli/command/image/list.go

and gets size from this code
https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/524986b1d978e1613bdc7b0448ba2cd16b3988b6/components/cli/cli/command/formatter/image.go

and finally you need
https://github.com/docker/docker-ce/blob/531930f3294c31db414f17f80fa8650d4ae66644/components/engine/daemon/images/images.go